# Would it be helpful to see question comments on the question edit page?

Tags: feature-request, comments

Would it be helpful for those occasions when someone is trying to edit a question to incorporate extra information provided in comments?

Would this have more negative effects than positive?

I know opening an extra tab is trivial, but this would make it even simpler.

I could also see too many comments cluttering the edit page for the majority of the time they are not needed, so maybe the option to hide or show comments would be better.

Comment: Yeah, and could we show them to suggested edit reviewers too?

Comment: Wow, Did this actually get implemented, or am I just now noticing it?

Comment: I think it was because you recently passed the 2k mark and the edit pages changed. 2k lets you edit inline, sub 2k gets sent through a special edit page.